# Create conditional access policy from Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have few users with 'Application Administrator' role. I don't want those users to manage all applications.

So, I tried to implement conditional access policy to block access. I came to know I can select users with directory roles while creating policy.

In Portal, I'm able to create policy and configure it with no loss. But I want to know if the same is possible using  Graph Api or not.

Anyone achieved this from Graph? Please help me with whole steps to follow.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and got the below results:***

You can make use of below **graph query** to create conditional access policy:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/identity/conditionalAccess/policies
Content-type: application/json
{

"displayName": "Block access to Application Admins.",
"state": "enabled",
"conditions": {
    "clientAppTypes": [
        "all"
    ],
    "applications": {
        "includeApplications": [
            "appID1",
            "appID2" 
        ]
    },
    "users": {
        "includeRoles": [
            "9b895d92-2cd3-44c7-9d02-a6ac2d5ea5c3"//ID of Application Admin role
        ]
    }
},
"grantControls": {
    "operator": "OR",
    "builtInControls": [
        "block"
    ]
}
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To confirm that, I checked in **Azure Portal** where policy is created successfully like below:

[image]

When I opened that policy, the users with **`Application Administrator`** role are selected as below:

[image]

Comment: Tqsm, is there any chance to update this policy from Graph Api after creation?

Comment: Yes, you can. What are the changes you want to make in this policy?

Comment: I want to change roles to User administrator and grantControls to allow access with mfa