# Edit existing conditional access policy from Graph

Tags: azure, graph, azure-active-directory, conditional-statements, policy

I created conditional access policy using this from my previous question reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74075644/create-conditional-access-policy-from-graph-api). It's working as expected.

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/identity/conditionalAccess/policies
Content-type: application/json
{

"displayName": "Block access to Application Admins.",
"state": "enabled",
"conditions": {
    "clientAppTypes": [
        "all"
    ],
    "applications": {
        "includeApplications": [
            "appID"
        ]
    },
    "users": {
        "includeRoles": [
            "9b895d92-2cd3-44c7-9d02-a6ac2d5ea5c3"//ID of Application Admin role
        ]
    }
},
"grantControls": {
    "operator": "OR",
    "builtInControls": [
        "block"
    ]
}
}
```

I want to change few properties like roles to User administrator and grantControls to allow access with mfa in this existing policy from Graph.

In Portal, we have edit option but is this possible from Graph? How to achieve that?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and got below results:***

I have one **existing** conditional access policy with below properties:

[image]

To update this policy via Graph API, make use of **below query** based on your requirement:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/identity/conditionalAccess/policies/<id>
Content-type: application/json

{
"displayName": "Require MFA to User Administrators.",
"state": "enabled",
"conditions": {
    "users": {
        "includeRoles": [
            "fe930be7-5e62-47db-91af-98c3a49a38b1"  //ID of User Administrator role
        ]
    }
},
"grantControls": {
    "operator": "OR",
    "builtInControls": [
        "mfa"
    ]
}
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, properties ***updated*** successfully like below:

[image]

You can get the **`id`** of User Administrator role like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure AD -> Roles and administrators -> All roles -> User Administrator***

[image]

**UPDATE:**

You can get the **`id`** of policy using below query:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/identity/conditionalAccess/policies?$filter=displayName eq 'policyName' &$select=id,displayName
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Tqsm, b/w where to find policy id? Cannot find it anywhere in Portal

Comment: Found it, tqsm!!